# Dejar activado o desactivado un boton al refrescar la página

Tags: php, javascript, html

mi pregunta es si existe la manera de refrescar la página y dejar el estado de los botones como estan, por ejemplo si el botón esta desactivado y refresco la página que el botón se quede desactivado o si esta activado que el botón se quede activado.

Gracias.

Comment: dentro de tu botón usa el atributo disabled , eso por defecto lo deja deshabiltado

Comment: podrias agregar mas detalles como tu codigo y lo que has intentado para poder darte una mejor solucion

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp

Answer (score 0):

Lo logre utilizando localstorage

```
        function inicio0(ida) {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","bd.php?idu="+idu+"&ida="+ida,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            document.getElementById("btn0").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("btn0.0").disabled = false;
            localStorage['btn0'] = 'true'
    }
```

El código al iniciar la página

```
        window.onload = function(){
                                          if(localStorage['btn0'] == 'true'){
                                                document.getElementById("btn0").disabled = true;
                                                if(localStorage['btn0.0'] == 'true'){
                                                        document.getElementById("btn0.0").disabled = true;
                                                }else {
                                                        document.getElementById("btn0.0").disabled = false;
                                                }
                                            }
                                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que seteas y obtienes los datos de tu localStorage de manera incorrecta ademas que necesitas hacer tus `if` individualmente, hice un pequeño ejemplo de lo que necesitas, espero y te sirva:

```
<button id="btn0">
Test1
</button>
<button id="btn0.0">
Test2
</button>

<script>

localStorage.setItem('btn0', 'true');
localStorage.setItem('btn0.0', 'false');


  if(localStorage.getItem('btn0') == 'true'){
     document.getElementById("btn0").disabled = true;
  }else{
     document.getElementById("btn0").disabled = false;          
  }
  if(localStorage.getItem('btn0.0') == 'true'){
     document.getElementById("btn0.0").disabled = true;
  }else{
     document.getElementById("btn0.0").disabled = false;
  }

</script>
```